# Spin verification - undefined reference to random and srandom

Tags: random, reference, undefined, spin, promela

I am currently learning Promela/Spin. The problem I have is that I can't verify my programs.

I create my pan files with: spin_64bits.exe -a x.pr  --- all's fine until here.

Now when I try to compile pan.c via **gcc pan.c** (gcc -o pan pan.c, whatever) I get an error that there are undefined references to srandom and random.

Note: It does work when I exchange those with srand() and rand() respectively, but to be honest, I don't want to open pan.c and edit it everytime I want to run a verification.

Do I have to use another compiler perhaps? I'm using MinGW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: see `MaxGhost`'s comment for better practice ("add these compile flags to your project: `-Dsrandom=srand` `-Drandom=rand`")

---

Seems like one or the other person stumbles upon this post, so I may as well make the answer that worked for me more visible.

Go to you **MinGW** folder, search for `stdlib.h` (C:\MinGW\include) and type in (somewhere along the other #defines, e.g.: below #include <_mingw.h>):

```
#define random rand
#define srandom srand
```

Comment: This is not the best option. Doing that, you're modifying headers installed by a package manager. Not good. Better is to add these compile flags to your project: `-Dsrandom=srand -Drandom=rand`